# Redirect sub-pages to parent without changing URL

Tags: routing

I am rewriting a Wordpress site and plan to turn part of it into an angular app.

The site has a bunch of sub-pages of the form `/recommendations/xxxxx`, and need to maintain these URLs for SEO purposes. But I want all these routes to return the `/recommendations` parent page whie keeping the rest of the URL present for Angular to process.

I think I need to use `add_rewrite_rule` but have got stuck, and the following does not work. I need wordpress to show the recommendations page even if there is an extra url-part subsequently.

```
function recommendations_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^recommendations\/(.*)\/?', 'recommendations/', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'recommendations_rewrite');
```

That said, this may be entirely wrong as I fear this will end up leading to URL rewrites, which is not what I want.

Comment: [This question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363731/redirecting-all-sub-sub-pages-to-another-subpage-using-htaccess) may help you.

Comment: I realise now that .htaccess cannot be the way forward and have rewritten the question to focus on wordpress hooks. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

No, you are on the right track as far as the `add_rewrite_rule` function is concerned. The generated rewrite rule doesn't send a 303 header.

The problem, in this case, is with your code which can be fixed easily.

On this line:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^recommendations\/(.*)\/?', 'recommendations/', 'top');
```

you are making WordPress to output a modified, custom `.htaccess` file with a nasty rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^^recommendations\/(.*)\/? /recommendations/ [QSA,L]
```

This not only is ugly RegEx (you get a double beginning of line marker -- `^^`) but the generated rule is broken because instead of the second `^` you should have `/`.

The solution is simple and it requires to locate the ID of the `recommendations` page / post which you would then use in the `add_rewrite_rule` function like so:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^recommendations\/(.*)\/?', "index.php?page_id={$page_id}", 'top' );
```

where the `{$page_id}` variable statement in the example should be the said ID. By the way, the [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function is presented on the WordPress Codex page.

After flushing the rewrite rules WordPress would serve an URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/recommendations/this/is/my/recommendation/
```

with the content of

```
http://www.example.com/recommendations/
```

Comment: Hm, for some reason this doesn't work for me. I am using ` "index.php?page_id={2}"` and I know that page with id 2 exists and the action is executed, what can be the reason ?

Comment: @gdfgdfg you need to write "index.php?page_id=2" - remove the {} brackets then it should work