# Redirect sub-page URLs to parent without changing URL

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, redirect, routing

I am having an issue with redirect rules for a single-page app that is on a sub-page of a Wordpress site.  I have followed this set of instructions pretty directly and am still having issues: [Redirect sub-pages to parent without changing URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193479/redirect-sub-pages-to-parent-without-changing-url)

The subpages are custom post types for business locations.  When someone visits `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/contact` it should pull up `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/` but the url needs to remain the same (The contact portion of the URL is part of a single-page Vue.js app on each location page, so it needs to stick around).  Here is my code:

```
//This function hooks in on post save
function add_location_deep_links( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if ( "location" != $post_type ) return; // If this isn't a 'location' post, don't update it.

    $slug = $post->post_name; //hollywood-ca

    add_rewrite_rule(
        "^{$slug}/[A-Za-z]",  //regex prevents trying to redirect the /hollywood-ca/ page
        "index.php?page_id={$post_id}", //redirect to post
        'top' // take precedence over other redirects
    );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

The problem is when I visit `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/contact` the page redirects to `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/` which prevents my single-page app from navigating to the contact tab.

If it helps, I have also written a couple of functions that change my URLs from `business.com/location/hollywood-ca` to the cleaner `business.com/hollywood-ca`.  I have tested these issues without those functions and am still having issues, so I don't think they are related.

Comment: `page_id` is only for the built in `page` post type. what is your CPT's query var? that's what you need to set.

Comment: I didn't set a custom query var so I assume it is `location`, what would be the change I need to make?

Comment: I wouldn't use add_rewrite_rule and flush_rewrite_rules with the save_post hook, but in init hook with $matches return by the regex. Just a point of view.

Comment: My understanding is that `flush_rewrite_rules` is a labor-intensive function (regenerating the `.htaccess` file) and should ideally only be called when something changes.

Comment: I don't really think that something changes, on save_post, you update an ID or create it. Your are not creating a new rule? For me, add_rewrite_rule must manage every new {$slug} according to the query, only one rewrite rule for your all your schema. Maybe I'm wrong but if you have a lot of post your options table (rewrite_rule key) will contain all your slug rules as I'm understanding your code. I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Milo's comment got me there:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    "^{$slug}/",  
    "index.php?location={$slug}", //changed query var to location
    'top'
);
```